# Do you know any Gurus with title of Rishi Maharshi Bramharshi or Devarshi presently?

Tags: yoga, rishi, guru

There have been many rishis like Maharshi Mahesh Yogi,Vethathiri Maharshi etc. Do such rishis exist in present times that use similar titles?